# Aligning memory on 16-byte and 32-byte boundaries

Tags: memory, alignment, sse, simd, avx

I'm doing several operations using SIMD instructions (SSE and AVX). As I understand, SSE instructions work best with 16-byte aligned memory, and AVX instructions work best with 32-byte aligned memory.

Would it be safe to always allocate memory aligned to 32-byte boundaries for optimal use with both SSE and AVX?

Are there ever any cases where 32-byte aligned memory is not also 16-byte aligned?

Answer (score 4):

> Are there ever any cases where 32-byte aligned memory is not also 16-byte aligned?

Alignment just means that the address is a multiple of 32.  Any multiple of 32 is also a multiple of 16.

The first google hit for "alignment" is wikipedia, and you can follow the links to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Definitions, which explains this in lots of detail.

Comment: @jbapple: re:your edit.  I was being rude on purpose, to discourage further questions this trivial.  What's next?  Is 100 a multiple of 10?  I also don't want anyone to upvote this answer, so the question can be deleted.  I know I could roll back your edit, but I'll refrain from doing that as a way of bowing to the pressure to be polite.

Comment: Peter, I am not interested in engaging in a debate with you in the comments of this answer about whether it is OK to be, in your words, "rude on purpose" to someone who doesn't know what "alignment" means in the context of computer memory.

Comment: If/when you go to Xeon phi then 64 bit alignment is recommended, so I tend to use that for all arrays that need speed. So why not use 64 bit alignment?

Comment: Am I the only person here who sees, "Of course not." as not being rude at all?

Comment: @Mysticial: yes, probably.  It's only slightly rude, but it implies that the asker should already know the answer, and thus not have asked in the first place, wasting everyone's time with a trivial question.  But now it's attracted an upvote, so at least one other person didn't know what alignment is.  My first version of the answer left out the "Alignment just means that the address is a multiple of 32" sentence, since I hadn't yet thought of any reason why anyone might need to ask this.  That's why I was grumpy, because it seemed like just a math question at first.

Comment: @Holmz: AVX-512 would want 64-**byte** alignment to avoid cache-line splits for ZMM loads/stores.  Is that a typo, or does Xeon Phi really only require 8-byte alignment?  Using 64B alignment when you don't need it wastes up to 63 bytes.  (Or up to 32B vs. 32B alignment for AVX/AVX2).

Comment: @Peter Cordes It took me a while to see that typo... I may have been using an underbyte.

Comment: @Holmz: I wouldn't recommend using 64B alignment when you don't need it.  Decreasing data density is generally bad for L1 hit rate, because it spreads your "hot" working set over more cache lines.  (i.e. decreases spatial locality of your workload.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I am hearing that this makes every element spread out on the 64 bit boundaries and not just the first element on the boundary (?) So should 32 bit Integers be align:4 ? And then what is a good approach for mixed SSE2/AVX/AVX2?  So that same code compiles on Xeon Phi and older machines? (Using #ifdef ?)

Comment: @Holmz: No, it's only an issue for small arrays / global structs, which is what I was thinking of when I said not to overdo it with alignment.  It's probably not a big a deal out of it for arrays.  OTOH, having all your arrays aligned to whole cache lines can lead to more cache bank conflicts when you access multiple arrays with the same index.  (Of course, big arrays often end up starting at a page boundary, leading to false dependencies, so explicitly skewing them can help.)  For decent-sized arrays, you don't need to worry about external fragmentation.

Comment: I probably need to take it offline... As I am beard-stroking.
Basically I am aligning the working vectors, and the rest is unaligned and I compile the code using the switch -unaligned .
So I might have an array that is:
    !DEC? ATTRIUBUTE ALIGN:64  :: A
    REAL DIMESION(32768,1024), ALLOCATABLE :: A
    !...
    ALLOCATE(A(Rank1A,Rank2A))
    !... Sometimes with an !?OMP DO PARALLEL 
    DO J = 1, Rank2A
       CALL Somefunction(A, B, Rank1A, Rank2A)
       ! B might be the sum(A) as a SIMD vectorized function
    ENDDO 
 
So should I align those 64, 4 or something else?

Comment: In macOS the compiler align any array to 16 Byte. Does GCC do that as well on 64 Bit system? What about MSVC?

Comment: @Royi: gcc on x86-64 uses 16B alignment for variable-size automatic arrays (on the stack), otherwise not necessarily (at least for small arrays).  I'm not sure about static arrays.  If alignment matters, you should use C++11 `alignas(16)` or C11 `_Alignas(16)` so you don't have to depend on specific compiler behaviour.